# Duplicação de mensagens no Chat na hora do Webinar (client side)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, chat

Olá, tenho um chat que na hora do webinar ao receber bastante clientes assistindo na hora de enviar mensagem, a mesma na tela parece duplicada, mas no banco não salva duplicada, segue o código do chat.

```
function salvarMensagem() {
    if ($("#btn-input").val() != "") {
        var id_entidade_chat = $("#id_entidade_chat").val();
        var id_versao_chat = $("#id_versao_chat").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("SalvaChat", "chat")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: "id_versao=" + id_versao_chat + "&id_entidade=" + id_entidade_chat + "&mensagem=" + $("#btn-input").val(),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function () {
                carregaChat();
                $("#btn-input").val("");
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                carregaChat();
                $("#btn-input").val("");
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Informe um texto antes de salvar");
    }
}
```

Aqui verifico se existe uma nova mensagem:

```
    function VerificaNovaMensagem() {
    try {
        var data = "id_versao=" + $("#id_versao_chat").val() + "&id_chat=" + $("#id_ultimo_chat").val() + "&id_entidade=" + $("#id_entidade_chat").val();
        $("#div_bodyChat").prepend($("<div>").load("/Aluno/chat/VerificaNovaMensagem", data));
    } catch (err) { }
}
```

E então a cada 5s atualiza:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        VerificaNovaMensagem();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Minha view:

```
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading top-bar-chat">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Pergunte aqui</h3>
            <p><small class="caracteres">145 caracteres restantes.</small></p>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="btn-input" name="btn-input" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Escreva sua mensagem aqui..." />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-chat" onclick="javascript:salvarMensagem()">Enviar</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_bodyChat" class="panel-body msg_container_base" style="max-height:320px">
        @Html.Hidden("id_entidade_chat", (object)ViewBag.id_entidade)
        @Html.Hidden("id_versao_chat", (object)ViewBag.id_versao)
        @Html.Hidden("id_ultimo_chat", Model.Count() > 0 ? Model.OrderByDescending(x => x.data_cadastro).FirstOrDefault().id_chat : int.MinValue)
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            if (item.id_entidade == ViewBag.id_entidade)
            {
                <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                        <div class="messages msg_sent">
                            <div class="header" style="margin-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px">
                                <span class="user-info" style="color:black;font-weight:700;max-width:140px">
                                    @item.tbl_entidade.nome_razao
                                </span>
                                <small class="pull-right text-muted">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                                    <time>@item.data_cadastro</time>
                                </small>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                @Html.Raw(item.mensagem)
                            </p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 avatar">
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.tbl_entidade.foto_nome))
                        {
                            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.tbl_entidade.foto_byte);
                            var imgSrc = String.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}", "image/jpeg", base64);
                            <img src="@imgSrc" alt="@(item.tbl_entidade.foto_nome)" height="64" width="64" class="img-responsive ">
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/imagens/profile.png")" alt="" class="img-responsive ">
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="row msg_container base_receive">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 avatar">
                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.tbl_entidade.foto_nome))
                        {
                            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.tbl_entidade.foto_byte);
                            var imgSrc = String.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}", "image/jpeg", base64);
                            <img src="@imgSrc" alt="@(item.tbl_entidade.foto_nome)" class="img-responsive ">
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/imagens/profile.png")" alt="" class="img-responsive ">
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                        <div class="messages msg_receive">
                            <div class="header" style="margin-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px">
                                <span class="user-info" style="color:black;font-weight:700;max-width:140px">
                                    @item.tbl_entidade.nome_razao
                                </span>
                                <small class="pull-right text-muted">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> <time>@item.data_cadastro</time>
                                </small>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                @Html.Raw(item.mensagem)
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>

    <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-white btn-round" onclick="javascript:salvarLike()">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i>                        
                </button>

                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-white btn-round" onclick="javascript:salvarDeslike()">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i>                                                
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Scrip completo na view:

```
<script>
$("#btn-input").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#btn-chat").click();
    }
});
$(document).on("input", "#btn-input", function () {
    var limite = 145;
    var informativo = "caracteres restantes.";
    var caracteresDigitados = $(this).val().length;
    var caracteresRestantes = limite - caracteresDigitados;

    if (caracteresRestantes <= 0) {
        var comentario = $("textarea[name=comentario]").val();
        $("textarea[name=comentario]").val(comentario.substr(0, limite));
        $(".caracteres").text("0 " + informativo);
    } else {
        $(".caracteres").text(caracteresRestantes + " " + informativo);
    }
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        VerificaNovaMensagem();
    }, 5000);
});
function salvarMensagem() {
    if ($("#btn-input").val() != "") {
        var id_entidade_chat = $("#id_entidade_chat").val();
        var id_versao_chat = $("#id_versao_chat").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("SalvaChat", "chat")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: "id_versao=" + id_versao_chat + "&id_entidade=" + id_entidade_chat + "&mensagem=" + $("#btn-input").val(),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function () {
                carregaChat();
                $("#btn-input").val("");
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                carregaChat();
                $("#btn-input").val("");
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Informe um texto antes de salvar");
    }
}

function salvarLike() {        
        var id_entidade_chat = $("#id_entidade_chat").val();
        var id_versao_chat = $("#id_versao_chat").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("SalvaChat", "chat")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: "id_versao=" + id_versao_chat + "&id_entidade=" + id_entidade_chat + "&mensagem=<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up green'></i>",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function () {
                carregaChat();
                $("#btn-input").val("");
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                carregaChat();
                $("#btn-input").val("");
            }
        });        
}
function salvarDeslike() {        
    var id_entidade_chat = $("#id_entidade_chat").val();
    var id_versao_chat = $("#id_versao_chat").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("SalvaChat", "chat")',
        dataType: "json",
        data: "id_versao=" + id_versao_chat + "&id_entidade=" + id_entidade_chat + "&mensagem=<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down red'></i>",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () {
            carregaChat();
            $("#btn-input").val("");
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            carregaChat();
            $("#btn-input").val("");
        }
    });        
}    

function VerificaNovaMensagem() {
    try {
        var data = "id_versao=" + $("#id_versao_chat").val() + "&id_chat=" + $("#id_ultimo_chat").val() + "&id_entidade=" + $("#id_entidade_chat").val();
        $("#div_bodyChat").prepend($("<div>").load("/Aluno/chat/VerificaNovaMensagem", data));
    } catch (err) { }
}
```

Comment: Você verificou a chamada "/Aluno/chat/VerificaNovaMensagem/" isolada? Ela retorna de fato apenas as novas mensagens?

Comment: Verifiquei aqui, na hora que clico enviar mensagem ele duplica/ triplica e depois atualiza para apenas uma mensagem, é na hora da ação no botão.

Comment: Faltou só a função carregaChat(), que é onde pode estar o problema. Passando o olho não me parece necessária no SalvarMensagem, uma vez que o post é feito e depois de 5 segundos a novamensagem seria carregada pela VerificaNovaMensagem()

Comment: Comentei os carregaChat() e não duplicou as mensagens, vlw

Answer (score 0):

Embora não apresentada na pergunta feita pelo autor, o comportamento ocorre por conta da execução em diversos momentos da função `carregaChat()`. Deduzindo que seria uma rotina apenas de inicialização, sua chamada em outros eventos deve ser removida ou ainda sua rotina revisada.

Destaco abaixo a função `SalvarMensagem()`, que é onde o autor detectou o problema, mas o mesmo deve ocorrer nas outras funcionalidades, `salvarDeslike()` e `salvarLike()`

```
function salvarMensagem() {
    if ($("#btn-input").val() != "") {
        var id_entidade_chat = $("#id_entidade_chat").val();
        var id_versao_chat = $("#id_versao_chat").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("SalvaChat", "chat")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: "id_versao=" + id_versao_chat + "&id_entidade=" + id_entidade_chat + "&mensagem=" + $("#btn-input").val(),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function () {
                //carregaChat();
                $("#btn-input").val("");
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                //carregaChat();
                //Adicionar feedback do erro para o usuário
                $("#btn-input").val("");
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Informe um texto antes de salvar");
    }
}
```